# How to check if an array contains only other arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking for a simple way/function to tell me if an array contains only other arrays or if there are values contained as well. For example,

```
$a = array(array(), array(), array())
```

should end up with a 'true' result but

```
$b = array(array(), 1, 17)
```

should end up with a 'false result.

I know I can do the following,

```
function isArrayOfArrays($a) {
    foreach ($a as $value) {
        if (!is_array($value))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way.

Comment: You are rocking... dont think harder :)

Comment: This should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com We all have nice solutions to offer : `var_dump (count(array_unique($a)) == 1 && is_array(array_unique($a)[0]));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter):

```
$isArrayOfArrays = empty( array_filter($b, function($item){
  return !is_array($item);
}) );
```

Or even shorter:

```
$isArrayOfArrays = array_filter($b, 'is_array') === $b;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with `is_array`, and see if all elements are true with [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
print_r(!in_array(0, array_map(is_array, $a)));
```

Basically, `is_array` is performed on each element of `$a`, so you get an array of booleans.  Then you check if this new array is all true.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fond of higher-order functions and the map-reduce paradigm:

```
/**
 * && as a function.
 *
 * This is our reducer.
 */
function andf($a, $b)
{
    return $a && $b;
}

function isArrayOfArrays($a)
{
    if (!is_array($a)) {
        return false;
    }

    return array_reduce(array_map('is_array', $a), 'andf', true);
}
```

This has slightly different semantics from your version, but I argue they are more correct (if it's not an array in the first place, it can hardly be an array of arrays can it?).

This formulation is arguably more elegant, but the difference is so small I would probably use the loop in actual code.